# Is there eslint rule for array multiline checking?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, eslint

I need to add eslint rule for the following case:

```
// bad
[
   'onClickSave',
   'onClickCancel'].forEach(bind(this));

// good
[
   'onClickSave',
   'onClickCancel'
].forEach(bind(this));
```

When defining an object or array with multiple lines, brackets must be on a new line.

Is there such rule in eslint or how could I accomplish it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there are no eslint rules for that. But there are proposals for [`array-bracket-newline`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/6073) and [`array-element-newline`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/6075).

If you want to try JSCS, it already has a rule [`validateNewlineAfterArrayElements`](http://jscs.info/rule/validateNewlineAfterArrayElements) which can be configured as below:

```
"validateNewlineAfterArrayElements": {
  "maximum": 1
}
```

ie, if you have more than one element in the array, each should be on a new line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Heads-up, the "validateNewline" link 404s. In other news, this seems to have been added to eslint now.

Answer (score 0):

```
"array-element-newline": [
         "error",
         'always'
      ],
```

The above will ensure a newline after each array element.

Coupling with:

```
"array-bracket-newline": [
         "error",
         {   
            "minItems": 1,
         },  
      ],
```

, would be my suggestion, as well.